# Can't load model using ContentTypeReader

Tags: c#, asp.net, xna, xna-4.0

I'm writing a game where I want to use ContentTypeReader. While loading my model like this:

```
terrain = Content.Load<Model>("Text/terrain");
```

I get following error:

```
Error loading "Text\terrain". Cannot find ContentTypeReader
AdventureGame.World.HeightMapInfoReader,AdventureGame,Version=1.0.0.0,Culture=neutral.
```

I've read that this kind of error can be caused by space's in assembly name so i've already removed them all but exception still occurs.

This is my content class:

```
[ContentTypeWriter]
public class HeightMapInfoWriter : ContentTypeWriter<HeightmapInfo>
{
    protected override void Write(ContentWriter output, HeightmapInfo value)
    {
        output.Write(value.getTerrainScale);
        output.Write(value.getHeight.GetLength(0));
        output.Write(value.getHeight.GetLength(1));

        foreach (float height in value.getHeight)
        {
            output.Write(height);
        }       
    }

    public override string GetRuntimeType(TargetPlatform targetPlatform)
    {
        return
            "AdventureGame.World.Heightmap,AdventureGame,Version=1.0.0.0,Culture=neutral";
    }

    public override string GetRuntimeReader(TargetPlatform targetPlatform)
    {
        return
        "AdventureGame.World.HeightMapInfoReader,AdventureGame,Version=1.0.0.0,Culture=neutral";        
    }
}
```

Does anyone meed that kind of error before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been encountering the same problem for a week, and finally decided to do a quick check on the whole "assembly" part.

I found a fix!

Essentially, when you go into AssemblyInfo.cs, you will see all the properties(ie Title, Description, etc.)

The Title, sadly made by XNA, is NOT what your runtime reader refers to. Its actually getting the initial name of the project, which it uses to track back to your application (exe) file in your project. Try either re-making your project from scratch, making sure to **keep your namespace the same as your project and never change it** , or give a go at **re-naming your exe file, found in the debug/obj folder in your project(i believe)**. hope I helped!

-Will

Comment: Actually I've resolved it earlier but thank you for your reply :) 
As you wrote that was the problem with wrong assembly names.

Comment: Glad you could figure it out :) Yeah haha the whole assembly in my opinion is poorly set up.